# C# Generics Strange Internal & Default Parameter Behavior

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to get a C# generic method to accept a new constraint on a type that has a default parameter?  I tried to do this with `TestGenerics<PublicDefaultParameter>()` below, and it gave a CS0310 "must have a public parameterless constructor" error.

Is there a way to get an internal C# generic method to call an internal constructor?  I tried to do this with `TestGenerics<InternalParameterless>()` below, and got the same error.

As an inexperienced C# programmer with experience in other languages, these restrictions seem completely arbitrary to me -- is there a way of making sense of this?

```
public class PublicParameterless
{
    public PublicParameterless() {}
}

public class PublicDefaultParameter
{
    public PublicDefaultParameter(int i=0) {}
}

public class InternalParameterless
{
    internal InternalParameterless() {}
}

public class Test
{
    public static T TestGenerics<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public static InternalParameterless TestNonGenericCaller()
    {
        return new InternalParameterless();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        TestGenerics<PublicParameterless>();

        //TestGenerics<PublicDefaultParameter>(); // error CS0310: The type `PublicDefaultParameter' must have a public parameterless constructor...

        //TestGenerics<InternalParameterless>(); // error CS0310: The type `InternalParameterless' must have a public parameterless constructor..

        TestNonGenericCaller();
    }
}
```

Comment: No; you cannot do that.

Comment: @SLaks: thanks. Is there a simple mental model for making sense of this?  This seems completely arbitrary.  Most of my experience is in C++ and Python, and every time I try to program in C# I feel like it is some half baked language, but I hope I just instead have a bad mental model for what should be possible in C#.

Comment: @Vlad, thanks, please move comment to answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default parameters are indeed syntactic sugar on caller's site. From the framework's point of view, it's just constructor with *one* parameter.

(As of correct mental model: many constructs in C# are not compile-time syntactic constructs, but real baked-in constructs existing in the compiled code. In particular, generics do exist in compiled code, in contrast to C++ where a template class is just a class at runtime. The same story is with default parameters: it is not about *syntactic* callability.)

Comment: But why do we get the same error for the internal constructor case?

Comment: @asker Because having a user-defined constructor (no matter public or internal) prohibits automatic generation of the default constructor.

Comment: The example using the public parameterless constructor works though. (run the code in the question exactly as it is). It is user defined here

Comment: @asker Because in this case there is a (user-defined) public parameterless constructor. The `new()` constraint requires a public parameterless constructor, no matter if user-defined or automatically generated.

Comment: @asker: `PublicParameterless` has a public parameterless constructor — pass. `PublicDefaultParameter` has a constructor which _can_ be called without parameters, nevertheless from the language's point of view it is not a parameterless constructor — fail. `InternalParameterless` has an internal parameterless constructor and no other constructors, but `new()` constraint requires a public parameterless constructor — fail.